# Laravel modify cells with expired date

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Sorry I didn´t know how to ask this question, but I want if a file reach his expiration date in each cell of expired date column just put "expired" otherwise just put his expiration date.
In my controller I create an variable called `$actualDate= Carbon::now();` and I send it to my view.
In my view I have this on table:

```
@foreach ($Files as $File)
<tr>
<td><a href="/File/{{$File->id}}">{{ 
$File->Code}}</td>
<td>{{ $File->created_at }}</td>
<td>{{ $File->person}}</td>
<td>{{ $File->category_file}}</td>
<td>{{ $File->status}}</td>
<td>{{ $File->employed}}</td>


@if($File->expirationDate < $actualDate)
<td>{{$File->expirationDate}}</td>
@else
<td>Expired</td>
@endif
```

If I put < on comparision all the column will be "expired" and if I put > it will be no expired Files even if there are ¿what can I do to solve this? I hope you can help me.

Comment: Whats the content of `$File->expirationDate` variable?

Comment: Is the expiration date is created by the next way: ```$File->expirationDate = Carbon::now()->addDays(15);```

Comment: All the files are 15 days older?

Comment: No, even if I create today it will be expired in 15 days. But by the comparision ```@if($File->expirationDate < $actualDate)``` the cell will set as "expired". I don`t even know why is doing the comparision at inversly.

Comment: Try: `dd($File->expirationDate, $actualDate)` to see the types of the variables.

Comment: yeah!! it seens ```Carbon::now()``` isnt working, it is sending a null value. And only brings me the last record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```php
@foreach ($Files as $File)
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/File/{{$File->id}}">{{ $File->Code}}</td>
        <td>{{ $File->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $File->person}}</td>
        <td>{{ $File->category_file}}</td>
        <td>{{ $File->status}}</td>
        <td>{{ $File->employed}}</td>

        @if(\Carbon\Carbon::parse($File->expirationDate)->lessThan(\Carbon\Carbon::now()))
            <td>{{$File->expirationDate}}</td>
        @else
            <td>Expired</td>
        @endif
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had already found it in other question, by doing this ```@if($File->expirationDate > \Carbon\Carbon::now())```. Anyway Thanks !!!